# head first python print_lol module error

Tags: python-3.x

> i am following head first python book using python3 version.
>   My directory in which i have my nester folder in 
>   C:\Users\Nimmi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\nester as in my image
>
> When i import module nester no error occurs on IDLE:
>   `>>import nester`
>
> i have following codde written in my nester.py:

```
def print_lol(the_list,level):
for each_item in the_list:
    if isinstance(each_item, list):
        print_lol(each_item)
    else:
        for tab_stop in range(level):
            print("\t", end ='')
        print(each_item)
```

> when i try to call nester.print_lol() function, it gives me error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "", line 1, in 
    nester.print_lol(casu)
AttributeError: module 'nester' has no attribute 'print_lol'

> where casu = ['holy day', 'life meaning']
>   Please tell how to resolve this error

Comment: I have to resolve Attribute error i am getting which says module 'nester' has no attribute 'print_lol''

Comment: can you try `dir(nester)` ?

Comment: I tried dir(nester) it gives following ['__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']

Comment: do you by chance have 2 files named the same? the output you provided doesn't contain your function, it should.

Comment: no i don't have any other file with the same name